# Matching LatLng points when ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement a feature where if you drag along a map it tries to match it up with previously defined points. In my Touch Listener I am trying to compare to LatLng points. However, none of my Logs are printing that there is a match. Can you not compare values within `ACTION_MOVE`

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();

      Point x_y_points = new Point(Math.round(x), Math.round(y));

      LatLng dragPoint = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);

      int eventaction = event.getAction();

      switch (eventaction) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); ++i) {
                        LatLng temp = markers.get(i).getPosition();

                        if (dragPoint.latitude == temp.latitude && temp.longitude == dragPoint.longitude) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        Log.d("Point: ", temp.toString());

                        if (dragPoint == markers.get(i).getPosition()) {
                            Log.d("Match: ", "Yes");
                        }
                    }

                    break;
             }

      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an `onClickListener` as well as your touch listener. It doesn't have to actually have any handling done within it, but for some reason the `ACTION_MOVE` event will only fire if you override the `onClick` function as well.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { }
```

Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: So add an onClick within the switch statement?

Comment: Add it in parallel with the the OnTouch, so it should be underneath your OnTouch function. For some reason, this is necessary when trying to catch the ACTION_MOVE event.